# Utility Mapper functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know if there is any way to write a mapper function in javascript, and by map functions I do not mean the ES6 map HOF, 
What I really need is when I get an response or data and I wish to produce a conditional result out of it, 
for example, if role:['ADMIN'] do this, 
if role:['HEAD'] do this, now it can be done with if else or switch but I do not want to write conditionals for this, as in future there is a possibility more conditions will be handled. So is there a way to create a custom mapper function which does this, it can also be useful in api calls as when a user has a specific role he/she can make this specific API call 
Please comment if you need more information.

Thank you

Comment: But how do you know what key are you going to get as response?

Comment: Sure there's a way to do that, have you tried?

Comment: If you want to know if a role is 'ADMIN' or 'HEAD' you literally need to use `if` or `switch` How else do you want to compare? You could create an object though with functions in it like: `let map = {"ADMIN": () => {}, "HEAD": () => {}}` and then do `map[role]()` but I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's the right way to do it but you could create an Object with functions in it.

This would look somewhat like that:

```
const map = {
    'ADMIN': () => { console.log('your role is admin') },
    'HEAD': () => { console.log('your role is head') }
};

map['ADMIN'](); // Outputs 'your role is admin'
```

But what if you, by any reason, received garbage data. Your code **will** error.

So you would either need to catch that error:

```
const role = 'blarg';
try {
    map[role]();
} catch(e) { 
    console.log('submittet incorect data') 
}
```

Or check if the `role` key exists in the object:

```
if(Object.keys(map).includes(role)) {
    map[role]()
}
```

But to be honest I still think I would do something like:

```
function handleRole(role) {
  switch(role) {
    case 'ADMIN': function_for_admin(); break;
    case 'HEAD': function_for_head(); break;
  }
}

handleRole(role);
```